# Не работает функция YouTubeGetID(url) в Wordpress админ

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Есть функция, которая выводит id видео youtube. Функция работает корректно, но не в Wordpress админке, при запуске сайта пишет ошибку в консоле:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

Красным горит: `(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/)` в коде:

```
function YouTubeGetID(url){
  url = url.split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);
  return (url[2] !== undefined) ? url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i)[0] : url[0];
}
```

В чем проблема и как ее можно решить?

Comment: Наверное два шт `url[2] `? Но непонятно зачем это. ВП и так поддерживает вставку с ютуба https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Не знаю, честно говоря, что означает url[2], но суть в том, что локально эта функция срабатывала нормально, а в ВП матюкается на эти символы (/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/). Вставка с ютуба? есть, шорткод, чтобы ссылку получить, не id. Но задача у меня состояла в том, что нужно было по ютуб API получить количество просмотрови нужен был id. Но задача решена,нашел функцию без этих символов. Спасибо за помощь!))